# Delay() bugged on table row reorder

Tags: jquery, removeclass

I have a simple script to change pages order for a cms. It is based on reordering table rows with jQuery. Now the issue is, that I want to remove the highlight class from the full row with a delay. It ignores the delay() and removes it right away.

The idea is, that when you hover over a row, it will add cell_rollover class to it. When you click on a up/down arrow, then the class remains to that row -- showing you, that the row moved. So after about 200 milliseconds, it should remove the class. It doesn't..

The code for the arrows:

```
$(".listtable_up, .listtable_down").click(function() {
    var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
    if ($(this).is(".listtable_up")) {
        row.insertBefore(row.prev());
    } else {
        row.insertAfter(row.next());
    }
    row.delay("200").removeClass('cell_rollover');
});
```

NOTE: The cell_rover class is being added to the row with a jQuery script:

```
$(".listtable tbody td").hover(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('cell_rollover');
}, function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('cell_rollover');
});
```

Why does this happen and how to fix it?

**EDIT**
Solution to my general idea is in the form of jquery effect highlight: http://jsfiddle.net/sZdre/1/
However, still trying to figure out, why the delay isn't working like it should..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is extremely late as I found this post looking for something else.

If you are still working on this and having problems, you should look into the queue.  The removeClass is not part of the queue and you need to add it to the queue to make the delay work, otherwise it just removes the class without waiting the specific time.

```
$(document.body).click(function () {
  $("div").show("slow");
  $("div").animate({left:'+=200'},2000);
  $("div").queue(function () {
    $(this).addClass("newcolor");
    $(this).dequeue();
  });
  $("div").animate({left:'-=200'},500);
  $("div").queue(function () {
    $(this).removeClass("newcolor");
    $(this).dequeue();
  });
  $("div").slideUp();
});
```

This example made the most sense to me.  I hope that helps you as I am currently moving through a similar issue and I already solved one like this a few minutes ago :)

Comment: Technically your answer is correct, so I switched it. I'm using `queue()` also currently.

Answer (score 1):

the delay is very less close to unnoticeable with the naked eye try

```
.delay(2000)
```

`2000 = 2 seconds`

```
duration: An integer indicating the number of milliseconds to delay execution of
          the next item in the queue.
```

[`jquery delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

**update**

```
$(".listtable_up, .listtable_down").click(function() {
    var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
    if ($(this).is(".listtable_up")) {
        row.insertBefore(row.prev()).delay(200).removeClass('cell_rollover');
    } else {
        row.insertAfter(row.next()).delay(200).removeClass('cell_rollover');
    }        
});
```

Comment: @Kalle H. Väravas dont use the quotes around the integer value

Comment: ok i dont see anyother reason why its not working try it without the caching `$(this).parents("tr:first").delay(2000).removeClass('cell_rollover')`

Comment: Technically I got it working, but using other ideas. I created a demo with the same parameters, however this is working absolutely differently then what I have going on.. http://jsfiddle.net/sZdre/

Answer (score 0):

So the original idea, to highlight the row that just got reordered is solved: http://jsfiddle.net/sZdre/1/

The delay bug is yet to figure out..

Answer (score 0):

Achieved desired behaviour with `window.setInterval()`

```
$element.addClass('cell_rollover');
window.setTimeout(() => $element.removeClass('cell_rollover'), 500);
window.setTimeout(() => $element.addClass('cell_rollover'), 1000);
window.setTimeout(() => $element.removeClass('cell_rollover'), 1500);
```

I suppose that `delay()` is not working because you probably use `tablesorter.jquery.js`. If that is the case, tablesorter has method called `delay()` that overrides jQuery `delay()` method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If any additional libraries would have been used, it would have been mentioned. So there for, no, no tablesorter.